# Tag Wiki Rejected Edit Question

Tags: support, tag-synonyms, suggested-edits

I think I might have made a mistake. I have been trying to get the Research Assistant badge and I am selfish for that. I like shiny new badges.

For that I have been adding information to tag wikis that do not have them. In that I add General Information and Tag Specific wikis.

If a tag wiki does not have any information, I copy paste a general summary from Wikipedia. Which is also CC license. I always include a English Wikipedia link.

My edits were being approved so far by users who have the approve privilege.

Today Oak rejected one of my edits. The tag did not have any tag wiki summary. Tag is [dragon-age-origins](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-age-origins). [Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/12193) is the review that I can see. The reason was I did not attribute it. I thought a Wikipedia link would suffice. Apparently not though.

I know CC license works by attribution. And I did not give proper attribution. But I did give the Wikipedia link always.

I do not have rollback privileges on tag wikis. Can a moderator review my approved suggested tag wiki edits, if they are copy-paste from Wikipedia or not? Or I can do that and notify someone in chat who has the privilege.

Or if a middle ground can be reached, can someone help with how best to proceed?

Here is my view: I have loved this site. I loved all the answers that I have gotten to my questions. But some questions about some games, when I roll my mouse over the tag on home page, it never answered what I wanted to know. Which is why I have taken such an undertaking. Mainly I wanted to know when a game was released, the genre, the platform, and how to buy it. This is why I am adding this information to tag wikis. Lately I am also adding information whether it was Windows, Consoles and which ones, MacX or Linux.

My apologies to the community. I was only trying to help.

Comment: There's no need to apologize; Don't overthink something like this! Getting a tag suggestion rejected doesn't mean your contributions aren't valid.

Comment: If you want to help, why don't you go through [your tag wiki edits](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/15184/desaivv?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) and suggest proper attribution for the ones that need it?

Comment: Oh, no worries. I wasn't implying that you somehow had some special responsibility to do this; just that if you wanted to help somehow, that would be the best way. If you do want to go around fixing problems with tag wikis, that's awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I do believe just linking Wikipedia - among other links - does not count as attribution, because you do not mention the text is from there. It seems you agree with me now. No worries - just suggest edits to [the wikis you have edited before](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/15184/desaivv?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) to remove or attribute the text copied from Wikipedia. I personally believe it's better to just provide your own short summary of what the game is.

Thanks for trying to make this site better!

Comment: @desaivv looks great!